# Node.js+Mongodb, two ajax request at the same time, one is suspended

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my environment:

1. Mac OS X: 10.7.5
2. Node.JS: v0.8.14
3. Mongodb: v2.0.6   + node-mongodb-native driver
4. Redis: 2.6.3
5. language: coffee-script

Here is the thing:
when the index page loads, two ajax requests will be sent:

```
var xhr1 = $.ajax({
    url: '/a',
    'dataType': 'json'
    'success': function(){}
);
xhr1.done(function(){...})
var xhr2 = $.ajax({
    url: '/b',
    'dataType': 'json'
    'success': function(){}
);
xhr2.done(function(){...})
```

both of then will query Mongodb, like this:

```
app.get('/a', functionA);
app.get('/b', functionB);


functionA = function() {
    var collectionA = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'a');
    collectionA.find().toArray(function(err, arrayA){
        var collectionB = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'b');
        collectionB.find().toArray(function(err, ArrayB) {
        });
    });
}
functionA = function() {
    var collectionB = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'b');
    collectionB.find().toArray(function(err, arrayB){
    });
}
```

collectionB in two requests are the same collection

each time, one request(1st or 2nd) was suspended, no response, no error. from the logs, I can see that request was stuck at the find() method. what's wired is after about two minutes, the page sent the same request again(I guess JQuery did that), then got the response.

in these two request, no redis request.

is it because mongodb? concurrent problem?

Comment: Neither jQuery nor any other framework ( at least known to me ) retries requests by default. Show us more code ( both client and server side ).

Comment: Please post more code, your route handlers lack basic Express stuff like sending back data from Node to jQuery.

Comment: How is your AJAX getting results ? There is no functionB and functionA is not returning response.

Comment: Do not use the new Collection. the correct usage is client.collect('b') as this will not work correctly.

Comment: I think I found the reason, this issue occurred each time I restarted the node.js server, seams it needs a little time (2 minutes) to establish connection with mongodb(maybe including load data to memory from disk).